# LIKE query not returning data as expected - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I really don't know what's the issue. I think my code is OK but the output is wrong. I don't know anything about WordPress, please help me.

```
elseif ($_GET['search']) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'head_to_toe_videos',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'post_title',
                'value' => $_GET['search'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
    );
}
```

Comment: You will have to show us some more code and explain what's the expected result vs what you're getting so we can help. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should execute your query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct but need to execute you query like this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$result = $the_query->get_results();

echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code your problem will solve.

```
    elseif ($_GET['search'] != '') {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'head_to_toe_videos',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key'   => 'post_title',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'post_title',
                'value' => $_GET['search'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
    );
    
    $result = new WP_Query( $args );
}
```

Comment: Is it worked or not?